# Select a cell from collection view while populating

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, uicollectionview

I am developing an application with `cocos2d` that fetches all of the Facebook photos of a given user and then populates them in a `CollectionView`. I get all of the photos `URL's` via a graph query and insert them in array list.

```
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error){
        NSArray *resultData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

        for (int i=0; i<100;i++) {
            NSString *sourceURL = [[resultData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"source"];
            [_imagesUrlList addObject:sourceURL];
        }

        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
        [collectionFlowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 7, 5, 7)];
        _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_masterView.frame.origin.x, _masterView.frame.origin.y+TOP_MARGIN, _masterView.frame.size.width, _masterView.frame.size.height-TOP_MARGIN) collectionViewLayout:collectionFlowLayout];
        [collectionFlowLayout release];
        _collectionView.delegate = self;
        _collectionView.dataSource = self;
        [_collectionView registerClass:[ImageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
        [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226.f/255.f green:228.f/255.f blue:221.f/255.f alpha:1]];
        [_masterView addSubview:_collectionView];
        [[LoadingView sharedLoadingView] stopTheLoadingActivityView];
        [[LoadingView sharedLoadingView] moveVertically:-30];

        [self loadImagesInView];
    }];
```

In order to test with a high number of photos I insert 100 times the picture url at index 0.
After that the images are loaded on a separate thread with the given url from the Facebook request, because `NSURLConnection` blocks the thread on request.

```
    -(void)loadImagesInView{
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (int i=0; i<[_imagesUrlList count]; i++) {
        if (_backed) {
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"out");
        NSString *sourceURL = [_imagesUrlList objectAtIndex:i];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sourceURL]];
        NSLog(@"conn %d",i);
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

                [_imageViewsList addObject:image];


                [_collectionView reloadData];




                NSLog(@"finish %d",i);

            });



    }
        });
}
```

The problem is that I cannot select a picture during the loading of the images in the view. The `didSelect` method is not even called until the method is finished. Could it be because of the `reloadData` that I call when an image is ready for insertion. Below you can see the methods for selection, diselection and populating the collection view.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    ImageCell *cell= (ImageCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *photoImg = [_imageViewsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.imageView setImage:photoImg];
    NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:indexPath.row];
    if ([_selectedCells containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rowNsNum]]) {
        [cell.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:255.f/255.f green:255.f/255.f blue:255.f/255.f alpha:0.5] CGColor]];
    }
    else {
        [cell.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.f/255.f green:0.f/255.f blue:0.f/255.f alpha:0.5] CGColor]];
    }
    return cell;
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ImageCell *imgCell = (ImageCell*)[_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([_selectedCells containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[indexPath row]]]) {
        [_selectedCells removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[indexPath row]]];
        [imgCell.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.f/255.f green:0.f/255.f blue:0.f/255.f alpha:0.5] CGColor]];
    }
    else {
        [_selectedCells addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[indexPath row]]];
        [imgCell.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:255.f/255.f green:255.f/255.f blue:255.f/255.f alpha:0.5] CGColor]];
    }
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ImageCell *imgCell = (ImageCell*)[_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([_selectedCells containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[indexPath row]]]) {
        [_selectedCells removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[indexPath row]]];
        [imgCell.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.f/255.f green:0.f/255.f blue:0.f/255.f alpha:0.5] CGColor]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

place    [_collectionView reloadData]; out side the for loop..

```
 -(void)loadImagesInView{
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
for (int i=0; i<[_imagesUrlList count]; i++) {
    if (_backed) {
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"out");
    NSString *sourceURL = [_imagesUrlList objectAtIndex:i];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sourceURL]];
    NSLog(@"conn %d",i);
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

            [_imageViewsList addObject:image];


            NSLog(@"finish %d",i);

        });

}
[_collectionView reloadData];
    });
```

}

Comment: yes but what if the user has for example 500 photos, he will have to wait more than 30 seconds probably to see the pictures.

Comment: the best solution for this is use AFNetworking. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking. Please follow the steps it will more help. Step1: download the AFnetworking frame work.  Add the afnetworking classes. step2: #import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"  step replace line as  ImageCell *cell= (ImageCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:kLoadingImage]; it can handle everything.